# Realtime Multiplayer game with MultipeerConnectivity really slow

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, multipeer-connectivity

I'm developing a multiplayer-game by using the MultipeerConnectivityFramework in Swift. My problem is, that's not really smooth and with a relatively high delay.

And with a high delay I mean, that the changes on the connected phone doesn't happen immediately, but with a delay which makes the game stuck.

So to start simple: Everytime a player touches the screen, a node should move on both screens. So of course I need to send a message everytime a user touches the screen. So in my `touchesBegan` method i call a send-method:

```
 func sendMessage(dict:NSDictionary){
        let messageDict = dict

        let messageData = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(messageDict, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted, error: nil)
        appDelegate.mpcHandler.session.sendData(messageData, toPeers: appDelegate.mpcHandler.session.connectedPeers, withMode: MCSessionSendDataMode.Reliable, error: nil)
    }
```

Like that:

```
sendMessage(["moved":MoveDirection.Left.rawValue])
```

Then, I receive it on the other device and run the function to update the node-position:

```
func handleReceivedDataWithNotification(notification:NSNotification){
        let userInfo = notification.userInfo! as Dictionary
        let receivedData:NSData = userInfo["data"] as NSData

        let message = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(receivedData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: nil) as NSDictionary
        if let mess: AnyObject = message.objectForKey("lostState"){
            gameOver = true
            createGameOverLabel(mess as String)
        }else if let mess: AnyObject = message.objectForKey("higher"){
            println(mess)
            let coNumber = mess as Int
            println(yourNumber)
            if(coNumber > yourNumber){
                leftAndRight = true
            }else{
                leftAndRight = false
            }
        }else if let mess:AnyObject = message.objectForKey("moved"){
            var moved = mess as Int
            var move = moveHeight/3

            switch moved{
            case MoveDirection.Left.rawValue:
                moveNode.position.x -= move
            case MoveDirection.Right.rawValue:
                moveNode.position.x += move
            case MoveDirection.Down.rawValue:
                moveNode.position.y -= move
            case MoveDirection.Up.rawValue:
                moveNode.position.y += move
            default:
                break
            }
        }


    }
```

So my question is: Am I doing something wrong? I've tested it on a real iPhone 6 and on a real iPhone 5. Are there any alternatives, beside GameCenter or other ways so that the sending/receiving works faster?

Comment: Don't know that it will make a difference, but is there a reason to use `NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted`.  You aren't personally reading the json, so adding extra whitespace and indentation will only make the packets being sent larger.

Comment: And test your connection's ping by sending the smallest possible packet back and forth for a while, measuring the time it takes to receive a reply. That's the time you can not optimize, and anything above that is time spent processing your package. I wouldn't be surprised if 99.9% of the time is simply lag due to high pings, especially if the connection is over the air/Internet rather than bluetooth or wifi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your problem is that you are trying to update the UI from a background thread rather than the main thread. That results is apparently long delays before the UI reflects the data received.

When data is received, didReceiveData:fromPeer is called on a background thread and if you post a notification from that method, that will not be on the UI thread.

Try using `dispatch_async`

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
     NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "handleReceivedDataWithNotification:", name: "MPC_DidReceiveDataNotification", object: nil)
})
```

Comment: It looks like it works. Thanks For your help. I've updated the question to the swift equivalent.